# Solving a non-linear 5 variable system

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following system for different values of the parameter `b`

```
system={y1 - (-1 + x) (1 + E^(-((1 - x + y2)/(5 z2)))/(20 z2)) + (
   E^(-((1 - x + y2)/(5 z2))) y2)/(20 z2) == 
  0, -100 (y1 - b/(
     1 + (y1 - y2)/(-1 + E^(1/4 x (y1 - y2))))) == 
  0, -100 (y2 - b/(
     1 + (y1 - y2)/(1 - E^(-(1/4) x (y1 - y2))))) == 0, 
 5 (1 - z1) - E^((-1 + x - y1)/(5 z1)) z1 == 0, 
 5 (1 - z2) - E^((-1 + x - y2)/(5 z2)) z2 == 0}
vars = {x,y1,y2,z1,z2}
```

Overall I will need about ~100 sets of solutions for this system (i.e, different values of `b`).

So far I'm trying to use `NSolve[system,vars]` but mathematica is stuck running, and looking for advise on a handling procedure of such equations so that an accurate solution could be obtained quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `NMinimize` :

```
sol[b_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{1, {y1 - (-1 + x) (1 + E^(-((1 - x + y2)/(5 z2)))/(
20 z2)) + (E^(-((1 - x + y2)/(5 z2))) y2)/(20 z2) == 
0, -100 (y1 - b/(1 + (y1 - y2)/(-1 + E^(1/4 x (y1 - y2))))) == 
0, -100 (-(b/(1 + (y1 - y2)/(1 - E^(-(1/4) x (y1 - y2))))) + 
y2) == 0, 5 (1 - z1) - E^((-1 + x - y1)/(5 z1)) z1 == 0, 
5 (1 - z2) - E^((-1 + x - y2)/(5 z2)) z2 == 0}}
, vars][[2]]
```

solution `b==1`

```
sol[1]
(*{x -> 1.23605, y1 -> 0.236065, y2 -> 0.236065, z1 -> 0.833334,z2 -> 0.833334}*)
```

**addendum additional constraint `{x > 0, y1 > 0, y2 > 0, z1 > 0, z2 > 0}`**

```
solN[b_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{1, 
Join[{y1 - (-1 + x) (1 +E^(-((1 - x + y2)/(5 z2)))/(20 z2)) + (E^(-((1 - x +y2)/(5 z2))) y2)/(20 z2) ==0, -100 (y1 - b/(1 + (y1 - y2)/(-1 + E^(1/4 x (y1 - y2))))) ==0, -100 (-(b/(1 + (y1 - y2)/(1 - E^(-(1/4) x (y1 - y2))))) +y2) == 0,5 (1 - z1) - E^((-1 + x - y1)/(5 z1)) z1 == 0,5 (1 - z2) - E^((-1 + x - y2)/(5 z2)) z2 == 0},
Map[# > 0 &, vars]]}, vars][[2]]

solN[10]
(*{x -> 2.64438*10^-8, y1 -> 9.22828*10^-6, y2 -> 0.0000405658,z1 -> 0.862207, z2 -> 0.863707}*)
```

Comment: it doest not find the currect roots, the roots I'm looking for are positive, and for example for b=10 you get negative roots

Comment: @jarhead That's an important infomation you didn't mention! Add `Map[# > 0 &, vars]` to the constraints!